# Не передаются данные между активити

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

В активити 1 через EditText вводится значение, сохраняется в Shared Preferences.

```
    SharedPreferences temperature;
    public static final String TERMO = "termo";
    public static final String T1_MORNING = "tmorn1"
    public static final Steing T2_EVENING = "teven1"




     temp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Dialog dialogTemp = new Dialog(HomeActivity.this);
            dialogTemp.setContentView(R.layout.dialogtemp);
            dialogTemp.setCancelable(false);

            Button btnOk = (Button)dialogTemp.findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);
            Button btnCancel = (Button) dialogTemp.findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);

            btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialogTemp.dismiss();
                }
            });
            btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {



                    EditText editText = dialogTemp.findViewById(R.id.textDialgTemp);
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int hour = calendar1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);


                    if (hour<=12){

                        String strTermo1 = editText.getText().toString();
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = temperature.edit();
                        editor1.putFloat(T7_MORNING, Float.parseFloat(strTermo1));

                        editor1.apply();

                    dialogTemp.dismiss();

                      }

                    else {
                        String strTermo2 = editText.getText().toString();
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = temperature.edit();
                        editor2.putFloat(T7_EVENING,Float.parseFloat(strTermo2));
                        editor2.apply();


                        dialogTemp.dismiss();}


                }

            });dialogTemp.show();


        }
    });

}
```

}

```
Далее передаю Extras

     stat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,GeneralStatistic.class);
            intent.putExtra("tmorning1",T1_MORNING);
            intent.putExtra("tmorning2",T1_EVENING);
            startActivity(intent);

Получаю Extras и пробую извлечь данные и построить график

    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;
    import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
    import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
    import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
    import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
    import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
    import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IndexAxisValueFormatter;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import static e.android.myapp.HomeActivity.T1_MORNING;
    import static e.android.myapp.HomeActivity.T2_MORNING;
    import static e.android.myapp.HomeActivity.T3_MORNING;
    import static e.android.myapp.HomeActivity.T4_MORNING;
    import static e.android.myapp.HomeActivity.T5_MORNING;
    import static e.android.myapp.HomeActivity.T6_MORNING;
    import static e.android.myapp.HomeActivity.T7_EVENING;

    public class TempStat extends AppCompatActivity {



BarChart barChart;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tempstatactivity);
    barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.bargraph);


    SharedPreferences tempprefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   float tmorn1 = tempprefs.getFloat(T1_MORNING,0);
   float tmorn2 = tempprefs.getFloat(T2_MORNING,0);
   float tmorn3 = tempprefs.getFloat(T3_MORNING,0);
   float tmorn4 = tempprefs.getFloat(T4_MORNING,0);
   float tmorn5 = tempprefs.getFloat(T5_MORNING,0);
   float tmorn6 = tempprefs.getFloat(T6_MORNING,0);
   float tmorn7 = tempprefs.getFloat(T7_MORNING,0);



    ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(0, tmorn1));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(1, tmorn2));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(2, tmorn3));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(3, tmorn4));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(4, tmorn5));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(5, tmorn6));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(6, tmorn7));

    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "°C");
    barDataSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

    barDataSet.setHighlightEnabled(true);
    barDataSet.setHighLightColor(Color.RED);


    BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(0);
    barChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP_INSIDE);

    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String> ();

    labels.add( "DAY 1");
    labels.add( "DAY 2");
    labels.add( "DAY 3");
    labels.add( "DAY 4");
    labels.add( "DAY 5");
    labels.add( "DAY 6");
    labels.add( "DAY 7");
    barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels));
    barChart.animateY(1000);
    barChart.setDescription(null);
    barChart.setData(barData);
}
```

}

В ожидаемом варианте: число вводится и передается в другую активити, там с этим числом строится график. Реальность: EditText работает, число вводится, при открытии активити с графиком, сам график пустой.

Answer (score 1):

> intent.putExtra("tmorning1",T1_MORNING); - вы просто передаете в extra строковую константу, а не значение

В вашем случае использование `SharedPreferences` совершенно лишнее. Сохраняйте значения в глобальную переменную класса и передавайте ее значение в extra.

Или же если использовать `SharedPreferences`, то получайте значения оттуда напрямую уже из вызываемого класса, не используя extra.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( context);

tmorn1 = prefs.getFloat(T7_MORNING, 0.0)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Скажите, в случае передачи с помощью переменной данные сохранятся при перезапуске приложения?

Comment: Если вам нужно сохранять значения после перезапуска приложения воспользуйтесь вторым вариантом из ответа.

Comment: Ничего не пойму, сделал так как вы советовали. График ничего не показывает. В поле графика все значения равны 0.

Comment: Добавьте обновленный код вызываемой activity

Comment: добавил обновленный код.